# Difference between зазнакомиться and познакомиться

Tags: грамматика

¿Какая разница между **познакомиться** и **зазнакомиться**:

> "Давным-давно, когда мои зубы еще держались за челюсть корнями, а не
>   штифтами, зазнакомились мы с приятелем с двумя девчонками".

Еще вроде бы пару раз встретил «замирились» вместо «помирились».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither have I encountered **`зазнакомиться`** previously. In Google results it mostly features in informal contexts in the sense of starting a romantic relationship (regardless of its duration). Basically just as in your example.

The prefix **за-** may be a borrowing from the verb **`завести`** of the locution **`завести знакомство`**. It's also used in a slangy verb **`замутить`** which among other things has the meaning **`to start a relationship`**

**`познакомиться`** is just a square verb whose meaning isn't limited to making acquaintance for the sake of sex.

Comment: Aha, so it's somewhere between "hit on" and "hook up"))) Thank you!

Comment: @CocoPop yup.... i mean yep

Comment: Very good!!! 

Comment: @CocoPop BTW "to hit on" and "to hook up" have etymological equivalents in Russian, to hit (ударить) - to hit on (приударить), to hook (зацепить) - to hook up (подцепить), which seem to only differ in register from the English verbs, приударить (to court) is just colloquial with no vulgar connotations, подцепить is rude with disapproving connotation of being either a wolf or a whore

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Thank you)))

Answer (score 1):

**Зазнакомиться** и **замириться** are both colloquial, maybe dialectal words meaning **познакомиться** и **помириться**. You should use the latter variants, although the former will be understood.

The versions with "за-" serve for the style-presupposing purposes, they imply storytelling in an informal, friendly manner, as well as mentioning natural and false teeth.

Comment: Interesting indeed! Elena, what did you mean by "style-presupposing purposes?"